# Problems on Cocos2d-x for iOS Programming

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am newbie to the CoCos2d-x Game engine. I am using the book "Learning Cocos2d".However, when I create a project, the "classes" folder doesn't contain the .m file. I can find the .cpp file only so that I cannot use the Objective C code (as the code in the course book). I have to convert the code from Objective C to Cpp. Is there any solution that Xcode can create a .m file for me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Cocos2d**: Obj.C Based iPhone only

[image]

You can find Cocos2d sdk here: [Download Cocos2d SDK](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download/)

**Cocos2d-x** : C++ Bsed Crossplatform

[image]

You can find Cocos2d-x sdk here: [Download Cocos2d-x SDK](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Download)